# Accessing external JavaScript function and class from angularjs controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am very new to Angularjs. 
I have an external java script called client.js. This file has a function

```
function Client() {
_instance_ = this;
this.client = null;
this.clientType = null;
}

ArcotClient.prototype.setAttribute = function(key, value, value2) {
 if (key.toLowerCase() == "flashupdateurl") {
    if (value != null) {
        this.flashUpdateURL = value;
    }
} else if (key.toLowerCase() == "javainstallurl") {
    if (value != null) {
        this.javaInstallURL = value;
    }
} 
ArcotClient.prototype.getVersion(){

   return version;
}
}
```

Now in angularjs controller file i want to access the function declared in client.js

```
var client = new Client();
client.getVersion();
```

Please help me how to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

assuming the client.js file is loaded before the controller that is trying to use it, i dont see a problem with doing what you outlined inside the controller function.

If that doesnt work, create a plunker the demonstrates the issue